# Does g++-5.1.0 with Boost support C++17?

Tags: c++, boost, g++, c++17

I'm trying to compile the C++17 specific gcd code using `g++-5.1.0 (2015)` and `Boost-1.71.0` on **Windows 7**:

```cpp
#include <numeric>

int main() {
  int x=90;
  int y=9;
  return gcd(x,y);
}
```

When I compile it with:

```
g++ gcd.cpp -IC:\Programs\boost-1.71.0\include -std=c++17
```

it says `error: 'gcd' was not declared in this scope`

If I `#include <boost/ratio/detail/mpl/gcd.hpp>` this time it says `error: missing template arguments before '(' token` referring to the gcd's (

Does `g++-5.1.0` properly support C++17? If so how to make it correctly handle the `C++17` code? Thanks.

Comment: gcd is in `boost/integer`

Comment: @user14717 That's right, the gcd is in `boost/integer/common_factor_rt.hpp` and its proper prefix is `boost::integer::` And now it works :) In this case it could be said that g++-5.1.0 with Boost can compile C++17 specific functions (gcd is reported to be introduced by the C++17) but using a bit different header files i.e. `numeric` vs `integer/common_factor_rt.hpp`

Answer (score 1):

`::mpl::gcd(x,y)` is not anything in C++17.

I suspect that you mean `std::gcd` instead.

Also, the odds of gcc-5.1 (released in April 2015) implementing `std::gcd` (a C++17 feature) is reasonably low. It could be implemented there - but it's not a sure thing.

Comment: It (`::mpl`) was a remnant of my last iteration which I forgot to remove. I've edited the post. If I make it `std::gcd` it is again: `error: 'gcd' is not a member of 'std'`

Comment: Then I suspect that gcc 5.1 did not implement that c++17 feature. A bit of exploration with Compiler explorer (using `std::gcd` not just `gcd`) suggests that it was added for gcc-7

Comment: Yes but gcc-5.1 accepts the `-std=c++17` option. If I change it to  for instance  c++16 or c++19 it says `unrecognized command line option '-std=c++19` which makes me think that it should support c++17 somehow.

Comment: And it does support C++17 - partially.  The paper proposing adding `gcd` to the standard (https://wg21.link/P0295) was not written until March 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to run with ::mpl, as it seems to be a helper struct for ratio. In the other hand, did you mean:

> boost::math::gcd(x,y);

Comment: If I prefix `boost::math::`then it says: `error: 'boost' has not been declared`

Comment: As for the `::mpl` you're correct, its  `gcd`somewhat unrelated to the `gcd`as we know it (greatest common divisor) but the reason I've tried it (by including `boost/ratio/detail/mpl/gcd.hpp`) is because when I do it, the compiler accepts it, i.e. (estimatedly) the `g++-5.1.0` is able to process Boost libraries (roughly speaking)